# AngularJS pagination manual update pages count

Tags: angularjs

I try to update the pages count http://bit.ly/1Fv6Q44 but I don't see it happens. Why ?

Comment: You put the button outside the controller, and you need to set the function with "()", like this `updatePagesCount()`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

First the expression in `ng-click` cannot be just a function name, you need to actually call the function: `ng-click="updatePagesCount()"`

Then, this ng-click is outside of your `ng-controller`, so not part of the controller, so doesn't have access to `$scope.updatePagesCount`.

The JS was ok, here is the fixed HTML:

```
<div ng-app="pageApp" ng-controller="pageCtrl">
    <div class="well well-small">
        <div pagination total-items="totalItems()"        
             page="currentPage"
             max-size="maxSize"
             boundary-links="true"></div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="updatePagesCount()">update</button>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ut3pvqm6/7/

Comment: I noticed that the pageSize variable makes it working incorrectly, look http://jsfiddle.net/ut3pvqm6/8/

Comment: That's because you forgot the `items-per-page` attribute to the directive, which I guess should equals `pageSize`. See http://jsfiddle.net/8w8ngdza/